# Storing CSV data in Ruby hash

Tags: ruby, hash

Say I have a CSV file with 4 fields,

```
ID,name,pay,age
```

and about 32,000 records.

What's the best way to stick this into a hash in Ruby?

In other words, an example record would look like:

{:rec1 => {:id=>"00001", :name => "Bob", :pay => 150, :age => 95 } }

Thanks for the help!

Comment: This isn't a very scalable practice. A simple database using Postgres, MySQL or even SQLite would be easy to build and access using Ruby DBI at a minimum, or an ORM like Sequel, ActiveRecord or Datamapper. They won't be quite as fast as an in-memory hash, but then they're a lot more scalable.

Comment: @Greg, I know that it's not particularly scalable but since the dataset is of a relatively fixed size and quite small right now it should be fine.  Thanks for your solution below, too :-)

Comment: @mbm the best way to do this is to use the `smarter_csv` gem - see my answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`Excelsior`](https://github.com/halogenandtoast/excelsior) rubygem for this:

```
csv = ...
result = Hash.new
counter = 1
Excelsior::Reader.rows(csv) do |row|
   row_hash = result[("rec#{counter}".intern)] = Hash.new

   row.each do |col_name, col_val|
      row_hash[col_name.intern] = col_val
   end
   counter += 1
end

# do something with result...
```

Comment: @JacobRelkin `Excelsior` is nice, but I still like `smarter_csv` better for it's features.

Answer (score 3):

Typically we'd want to use an `:id` field for the Hash key, since it'd be the same as a primary key in a database table:

```
{"00001" => {:name => "Bob", :pay => 150, :age => 95 } }
```

This will create a hash looking like that:

```
require 'ap'

# Pretend this is CSV data...
csv = [
  %w[ id     name  pay age ],
  %w[ 1      bob   150 95  ],
  %w[ 2      fred  151 90  ],
  %w[ 3      sam   140 85  ],
  %w[ 31999  jane  150 95  ]

]

# pull headers from the first record
headers = csv.shift

# drop the first header, which is the ID. We'll use it as the key so we won't need a name for it.
headers.shift

# loop over the remaining records, adding them to a hash
data = csv.inject({}) { |h, row| h[row.shift.rjust(5, '0')] = Hash[headers.zip(row)]; h }
ap data

# >> {
# >>     "00001" => {
# >>         "name" => "bob",
# >>          "pay" => "150",
# >>          "age" => "95"
# >>     },
# >>     "00002" => {
# >>         "name" => "fred",
# >>          "pay" => "151",
# >>          "age" => "90"
# >>     },
# >>     "00003" => {
# >>         "name" => "sam",
# >>          "pay" => "140",
# >>          "age" => "85"
# >>     },
# >>     "31999" => {
# >>         "name" => "jane",
# >>          "pay" => "150",
# >>          "age" => "95"
# >>     }
# >> }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Ruby Gem `smarter_csv`, which parses CSV-files and returns array(s) of hashes for the rows in the CSV-file.  It can also do chunking, to more efficiently deal with large CSV-files, so you can pass the chunks to parallel Resque workers or mass-create records with Mongoid or MongoMapper.

It comes with plenty of useful options - **check out the documentation on [GitHub](https://github.com/tilo/smarter_csv)**

```
require 'smarter_csv'
filename = '/tmp/input.csv'
array = SmarterCSV.process(filename)

=>

[ {:id=> 1, :name => "Bob", :pay => 150, :age => 95 } ,
 ...
]
```

See also:

- https://github.com/tilo/smarter_csv
- http://www.unixgods.org/~tilo/Ruby/process_csv_as_hashes.html

Answer (score 0):

```
Hash[*CSV.read(filename, :headers => true).flat_map.with_index{|r,i| ["rec#{i+1}", r.to_hash]}]
```